# How to determine whether a JPA row-limited query could have more rows?

Tags: jpa

I'm using a JPA query like this:

```
x = em.createQuery("SELECT w FROM widgets w").setMaxResults(2000).getResultList();
```

The `widget` table can be huge, so the limit is necessary.  However, I'd like to know whether there were more rows that could have been returned if `setMaxResults()` hadn't been used.

How can I do that without running a second query that uses the QL's `count(*)` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may sound a bit primitive, but you could set max results to the desired limit +1 and check the number of items returned. It's at least a lot cheaper than executing a second query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It makes sense.  It's not as elegant as I hoped for, but after I saw the SQL query generated by JPA, I realized why it can't possibly know if there are more rows or not.  It runs the original query as a subquery of a query with row limits.  As a result, it appears that the subquery must complete before it limits the rows.  That can take a **long** time.  So I may have avoided a second query that uses `count(*)`, but this solution is very, very slow.  I'll probably end up using the second query to improve performance.